# Derivative of all real x

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Find the derivative of the function for all real
$x$.

$f(x)= (\sin(x^\frac 13)^3$)

It also gives a hint saying extra attention needs to be placed on $x = 0$. Getting the basic derivative isn't the problem for me, it is getting it to work for all real $x$. I'm thinking a piecewise function may do it but I cannot get the derivative for $x = 0$ using the definition of a derivative.

One more thing I missed, it asks if the derivative is continuous on all real $x$ or not so it seems to contradict itself since the derivative does not exist when $x<0$. It does however hint towards $x=0$

Comment: Is it $(\sin ^2(x^{1/3})^3$ or $\sin^2(x^{(1/3)})^3$?

Comment: sorry about the confusion, I edited the function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is vague. The usual derivative away from zero is
$$\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{x}\right)\cos\left(\sqrt[3]{x}\right)}{x^{2/3}}$$
You can show that the limit of this as $x\rightarrow 0$ is $1$ by a Taylor expansion. For values of $x<0$, the derivative takes on complex values.

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way to show that the limit as $x→0$ is 1 without a Taylor expansion?